# Evaluate all combination in cuda

Tags: cuda

all. I have 3 arrays with different lengths, say x, y, z. I want to calculate sum of `f(x)*f(y)*f(z)*f(x,y,z)` where f are different functions. At the moment, I am using recursive loops in C. Because the numbers are very large, the C code is very slow. I just wonder what is the best way to do it in CUDA? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The question you have asked is a bit vague.

First, you transfer the arrays, x,y,z into GPU Global Memory. If x+y+z< 512, you can use the concept of shared memory (without the help of loops). If it is not satisfied, you can use loops. You evaluate f(x),f(y),f(z),f(x,y,z) separately and multiply them (single thread for each multiplication). Also, the lengths x,y,z should be consistent with the array multiplication property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to find the sum not product.The problem in fact is to find convolution of 4 discrete binomial random variable where the sum is a constant.

Comment: Check out the CUFFT library of cuda. It doesnt support 4. It support 2D convolution. Are the functions f(x),f(y),f(z) and f(x,y,z) are different?

Comment: The functions are binomial distributions with different probabilities. Anyway, I will have a look at the CUFFT library. Thanks.